# Set Marker in matplotlib to be a single pixel with scatterplot

Tags: matplotlib

I have a very large dataset that I am plotting in `matplotlib`.  I would like to make the marker exactly `1 pixel in size`.

I am using a scatter plot. I have tried changing markersize but this always results in a circle with varying diameters. I know I can change the marker to other characters but I want to set it to be exactly 1 pixel.

How can I make the `marker exactly 1 pixel`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your marker type as ',g' or pixel type and in this case colour is green pick your own colour - this is the m parameter in `plot(Xs, Ys, m)`